# Как найти причину возникновения signal Bus error (7)?

Tags: debian, отладка, apache2, php7, xdebug

Доброго времени суток.

Дано:

- Есть сайт на проде, крутится под управлением apache2 с mod_php.
- Сайт крутится под управлением php7.0, т.к. ioncube в данном случае поддерживает максимум эту версию, а перекодировать возможности нет.

Периодически сайт возвращает 324 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (либо 500, если работает под управлением nginx + php-fpm). Ошибка была замечена только со стороны непосредственно клиентской части; в админке она не возникает. И теперь самое интересное: я включил логирование на максимум как со стороны apache2, так и со стороны php. Логи php молчат, а вот апач пишет:

> AH00051: child pid nnnnn exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Я гуглил, ответы везде разнятся: кто-то сетует на память, кто-то говорит о неправильно скомпилированном апаче, кто-то о проблемных модулях или кривом php-коде. Лично я уверен на 97%, что в коде, т.к.:

- Сайт пеерносился на другой хостинг, запускался на локалке, но ошибка никуда не уходила.
- На том же хостинге в соседних директориях лежат другие сайты, с ними проблем нет.
- Дистрибутивы апача и php - дефолтные из репозиториев debian, де-факто тут была уже предустановленная система со всеми популярными модулями.
- Я пробовал влючать и выключать модули php, менять mpm, заводить сайт под nginx - все тщетно, ошибка так или иначе появляется.

Исходя из этого, я делаю вывод о кривом коде. Подметил также, что ошибка появляется как правило при нескольких одновременных запросах. Т.е. если я буду просто на локальной машине кликать по ссылкам, то ошибки не будет. Однако, если запустить:

> ab -n 50 -c 10 "url"

то её можно увидеть в логах. Я уже консультировался со знакомыми разработчиками, писал в тех поддержку хостинг; результатов это не принесло. Вопросы следующие:

1. Как вообще отлавливать подобного рода ошибки?
2. Существуют ли отладчики php кода для подобного рода проблем? И если существуют, то прошу ткнуть меня в них.

Comment: А если просто системные логи посмотреть (dmesg, например)? Может банально памяти не хватает, мб приходит ООМ или что-то в этом роде...

Comment: @nobody Системные логи смотрел, они молчат. ООМ не наблюдается.

Comment: в coredump что? раз уж апач пишет про него. Смотреть через gdb можно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5115653/10983392